# Deleting schemas in loop in pgsql script: out of shared memory

Tags: postgresql

I have code (cut out all unnecessary logic)

```
    DO $$ DECLARE
      schema_name text;
    BEGIN
      FOR schema_name IN
        SELECT DISTINCT table_schema
        FROM information_schema.tables
      LOOP
          BEGIN
                EXECUTE 'DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS ' || schema_name || ' CASCADE';
                RAISE NOTICE 'Dropped schema %', schema_name;
              END IF;
            EXCEPTION WHEN others THEN
            RAISE NOTICE '%', SQLERRM;
        END;
      END LOOP;
      RAISE NOTICE 'Dropped % schemas', dropped;
    
    END $$;
```

It is providing out of shared memory error.
How i can understand, this function run in single transaction and of course there is no way shared memery can accommodate all shemas. So how can i handle it? I don't need run it in transaction.
(And i don't need to delete all the schemas, there is still a lot of logic that i cut out)
postgres version - 9, schemas count ~300, full error log: psql:name.sql:15: NOTICE: out of shared memory.

Comment: You also cut out all the necessary information: 1) Postgres version. 2) Number of schemas involved. 3) The actual complete error message. **ADD information as update to question**.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver i have added this information, but i am not understanding for what. my question: how to delete schemas without overall transaction.

Comment: 1) Postgres version 9 does not mean anything as there are 6 major versions of Postgres that start with 9. 2) All those versions are past EOL and no longer supported. 3) You can't run this outside a transaction.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver That is, the task of deleting, for example, 20 GB schemes using one function, is unsolvable in principle?

Comment: I would say it is not a good idea. The error is coming from a resource limitation, so it is conceivable more resources(memory) might solve the issue. There is also the possiblity it is a bug in your version of Postgres.  Hard to say without knowing what the resources are or the exact version number for Postgres.

Answer (score 0):

Transaction management in functions and anonymous blocks can get complicated. Putting `RAISE NOTICE 'xact_id: %', pg_current_xact_id_if_assigned ();` at areas of interest in the code can give insight into how transactions are working.

The following anonymous block drops each schema using separate transactions:

```
DO
LANGUAGE plpgsql
$BLOCK$
DECLARE
  drop_count integer := 0;
  error_count integer := 0;
  rec record;
  drop_statement text;
BEGIN
  FOR REC IN SELECT s.schema_name
               FROM
                 information_schema.schemata s
              WHERE
                s.schema_name NOT IN ('information_schema', 'pg_catalog', 'pg_temp_5', 'pg_temp_6', 'pg_toast', 'pg_toast_temp_5', 'pg_toast_temp_6', 'public')
              ORDER BY s.schema_name LOOP
    BEGIN
      drop_statement := FORMAT($$DROP SCHEMA %I CASCADE$$, rec.schema_name);
      EXECUTE drop_statement;
      RAISE NOTICE 'Dropped schema %', rec.schema_name;
      drop_count := drop_count + 1;
    EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
      RAISE NOTICE '%', drop_statement;
      RAISE NOTICE '%', sqlerrm;
      error_count := error_count + 1;
    END;
    COMMIT;
  END LOOP;
  RAISE NOTICE '%', FORMAT($$drop_count: %s, error_count: %s.$$, drop_count, error_count);
END
$BLOCK$;
```

This block cannot be run inside of another transaction.